# Sharing data between angularjs services without a circular dependency error?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, synchronization, angularjs-service

I'm trying to build an angular application that will continue to function with an unreliable connection (i.e. mobile).

So far I have Services for each of my models (for example):

- Classes
- Students
- Grades

When a new instance of each model is created, it's given a guid until I can retrieve an ID from the server.

The problem comes when I try to hook them up to my sync service. Ideally, the class, student and grade services need access to the sync service and vice versa, so new objects can be passed to the sync service, then the sync service can update the model in it's service directly when it's managed to contact the server for an ID. If I try and inject the services into one-another, I get a circular dependency error.

How can I go about sharing data between these services? I'd really like to try and avoid duplicating code to synchronize the models across each individual service (that would also mean a larger number of requests)?

Edit:

Here's a simplfied example of what I'd like to achieve:

```
angular.module('App')
    .service('sync', function sync(students) {

        var objectsToBeSynced = [];

        function resync() {
            // $http() to process and manage the pending objects
            /**
             * If request returns success, write into students.students[newIdFromServer] = students.students[oldId];
             * then delete students.students[oldId];
             */
            setTimeout(resync, 10000);
        }

        this.addToSync = function(object) {
             objectsToBeSynced.push(object);   
        }
    }

angular.module('App')
    .service('students', function students(sync) {
        var students = [];
        this.students = students;

        this.addStudent = function(student) {
         sync.addToSync(student);   
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

All services depend upon `sync` service. So you only need to add the sync service dependencies in your other service.

If the model object is same then any changes done to model by sync service like replacing the id would already be available to other three service.

You can implement insert method on the service to return a promise with the updated object if you want.

**Update:** Looking at your code i still feel you do not need to add reference for student service in `sync` service as long as the object that the sync service works on is the same that was send by any of your three services.

So

```
function resync() {
            // $http() to process and manage the pending objects
            /**
             * If request returns success, and returns new id just update the existing object that is inside the objectsToBeSynced array, assuming you can correlate for which object you make request */
            setTimeout(resync, 10000);
        }
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your answer - I updated my question with a simple example of what I'm trying to do. Could you take another look/try to explain again?

Answer (score 0):

> Ideally, the class, student and grade services need access to the sync service and vice versa,

I suspect the vice-versa isn't needed. Class, Student, and Grade should all be able to pass the data to your `sync` service that needs to be synced up to the server.

It sounds like it's a bit like a `$http`, but with a queue. The usual Angular `$http` doesn't need to know about your model services, it just accepts data and uses it. Your `sync` service should be able to do the same.

As a sidebar: I've previously implemented a far-too-complicated queue in a similar way, but then I discovered [http interceptors](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24http). You might want to have a look at what you can do with `responseError` and automatically retry any requests after a delay, or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the promises returned by `$http` solve this problem, but I am assuming you're doing ONE `$http` with a batch of new objects, and not multiple `$http` requests, one for each object?

In that case, I think the best solution is using Angular events.  `$emit` from `sync` for each `newIdFromServer` that comes back, and listen for those events in each object that requires `newId`s

```
.service('sync', function sync($rootScope) {  // NOTE: inject $rootScope

    var objectsToBeSynced = [];

    function resync() {
        // $http() to process and manage the pending objects
        /* If request returns success, then for each new ID returned from 
         * server, do $rootScope.$emit('student.saveSucess', [oldId], [newIdFromServer]);
         */
        setTimeout(resync, 10000);
    }

    this.addToSync = function(object) {
         objectsToBeSynced.push(object);   
    }
})

.service('students', function students($rootScope, sync) {  // NOTE: inject $rootScope
    var students = [];
    this.students = students;

    this.addStudent = function(student) {
     sync.addToSync(student);   
    }

    $rootScope.$on('student.saveSucess', function(event, oldId, newIdFromServer) {
      students.students[newIdFromServer] = students.students[oldId];
      delete students.students[oldId];
    });
});
```